# use SHAP values to explain a PCA-selected dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest, pca, shap

I'm using a RandomForestClassifier model, which I’d like to explain using Shapley values.
The data (which contains 150 features) was first run through a PCA selector, which converted it into 3 new features, and then this selected reduced-data was given to a RandomForestClassifier model.
The model is then given to shap.Explainer().
The problem is, I’d like the shap to explain the model with the original 150 features, and not with the 3 pca components. Therefore I called the shap.Explainer() with the original data:

```
#the selector:
fs_all_pca = PCA(n_components=3).fit(X)
X_all_pca = fs_all_pca.transform(X)

#the model:
model = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, min_samples_split=4, n_estimators=200, min_samples_leaf=3, class_weight=class_weights)
model.fit(X_all_pca, y)

#explain with shap:
explainer = shap.Explainer(model.predict, X)
shap_values = explainer(X)
```

However I get this error:

```
raise ValueError(
ValueError: X has 150 features, but RandomForestClassifier is expecting 3 features as input.
```

Is there a way to run shapley for the pca+model, with the original data before it passed through the pca selection stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're fitting your `model` on `X_all_pca` having 3 features:

```
fs_all_pca = PCA(n_components=3).fit(X)
X_all_pca = fs_all_pca.transform(X)
model.fit(X_all_pca, y)
```

However, when you're predicting you want to feed all the features:

```
explainer = shap.Explainer(model.predict, X)
```

Hence your error message.

It must be more or less:

```
explainer = shap.Explainer(model.predict, X_all_pca)
```

If you for some reason want to do analysis for all features (why do PCA then???), do a pipeline and feed it through `KernelExplainer`

Comment: The reason for analyzing all features is that I want to compare the results to other models running on the same data, so I need to have the importance of all features.

Comment: If I may, I'll advise you to put effort together to prepare an sklearn pipeline including PCA transform that will accept all the features and output predictions. And then ask how you can feed that pipeline through SHAP. Though, I think there are much better approaches in understanding what's going on with your data (and model) including factor analysis and the like, to serve your goals.